# How would I evaluate the following integral in terms of Catalan's constant $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^x}{1+e^{2x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, catalans-constant

How would I evaluate the following integral in terms of Catalan's constant?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^x}{1+e^{2x}}$$
I am pretty sure you have to turn the integral into a series somehow, because we can write catalans constant as a series. $$G=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

I am just not sure how to go about turning the integral into a series, I think I would need to do a $u$ substituion first, but I don't think $u=e^x$ works, and I couldn't think of any other plausible $u$ subs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{x}}{1+e^{2x}}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty x e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\\\\
&=G
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I'd include why you can change the order of sum and integration.

Comment: I prefer using $C$ for Catalan's constant; is this also common?

Comment: @Jakobian - Because of the linearity of continuous integrals.

Comment: @KevinNivek linearity of continuous integrals?

Comment: @Jakobian - A continuous integral of a sum is equal to the sum of the integrals.

Comment: @KevinNivek I don't understand. What is a continuous integral?

Comment: I think you have some theorem for continuous functions in mind, but I'd argue as follows. The partial sums are bounded by an integrable function $\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}$, hence we can change the order of sum and integration by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. (I wasn't asking for an explanation btw, it was a suggestion for Mark to add)

Comment: @jakobian Uniform convergence suffices.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm sure that it does for finite intervals, but not in general. Here, Lebesgue integral is needed.

Comment: @Jakobian There are standard theorems from Advanced Calculus that account for interchanging orders of operation on improper Riemann integrals with unbounded limits.  All we need here is that the integral $$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n xe^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx$$converge uniformly for $N\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Perfect. Your answer is nice and cute.

Comment: @user0410 Thank you.  Pleased to hear it was useful.